# How destructuring function params with defaults work in ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
const test = ({ foo = 'foo', bar = 'bar' } = {}) => {
  return { foo, bar };
};

test(); // { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }
test({}); // { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }
test({ foo: 'cat' }); // { foo: 'cat', bar: 'bar' }
```

But if i rewrite it in TS

```
const test = ({
  foo = 'foo',
  bar = 'bar',
}: { foo: string; bar: string } = {}) => {
  return { foo, bar };
};
```

`= {}` will cause error because of type mismatch (but as we see in first example — there is no undefined params and should be no type mismatch).

How to rewrite JS example in TS properly?

Comment: `{ foo?: string; bar?: string }` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your ts file :

```
const test = ({
  foo = 'foo',
  bar = 'bar',
}: { foo?: string; bar?: string } = {}) => {
  return { foo, bar };
};
```